# Is "ire" used correctly here? "Iosaphatum salutem ite."

Tags: grammar-choice, verbs, syntax, accusative

Can *ire* be used in this way? "Iosaphatum salutem ite." (I go to Iosephat for shelter.) Furthermore, is the two accusatives correct? This sentence is based on a Sanskrit construction, and I do not know if Latin can do this in the way that Sanskrit can.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context for this usage? Is this just your translation attempt of "I go to Iosephat for shelter", or are you seeing it in some work?

Comment: It is an adaption of the Sanskrit phrase "Buddhaṃ śaraṇaṃ gacchāmi" (Buddha+accusative, shelter+accusative, then "I go" (gacchāmi) , I am trying to explain declension to someone and I was wondering if I could make the same grammatical construction in Latin so that is was less confusing.

Comment: It seems that you have not yet taken [the site tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour). I warmly recommend that you go all the way through it. It will only take a minute.

Comment: Say, does the Sanskrit verb _gacchāmi_ take two accusatives? The [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/गच्छति#Sanskrit) doesn't mention anything, but of course they might have omitted that or it might be a common feature of Sanskrit verbs. If not, though, then _śaraṇaṃ_ might be an appositive (explained further in my answer).

Comment: Answering my own question, from p. 27 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=pj5IAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA81&ots=8XMqULFns3&dq=gacch%C4%81mi&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q=gacch%C4%81mi&f=false), it appears that _gacchāmi_ does have a sense of going to _X_ to ask for or to receive _Y_, where _X_ and _Y_ are both in the accusative—analogous to some Latin verbs, but not (AFAIK) _ire._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I go" is **eō**. *Īte* is the plural imperative: "Go, y'all!"

Some Latin verbs take [two accusatives](https://books.google.com/books?id=CBsXAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22dative%20of%20the%20purpose%20or%20end%22&pg=PA244#v=onepage&q=%22two%20accusatives%22&f=false), like *dīcō,* "I tell [person] [what I say]", or *rogō,* "I request [person] [what I want]." However, I don't think that works with *īre* because it doesn't naturally have two things that could serve as its object. Consequently, in this sentence:

> Iosaphatum salutem eo.

*salūtem* will be understood as an appositive: "I go to Buddha the salvation" or "I go to Buddha as salvation." This might be exactly what you're looking for even though grammatically it doesn't parallel the use of two accusatives with Sanskrit "[*gacchāmi*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pj5IAQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA81&ots=8XMqULFns3&dq=gacch%C4%81mi&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q=gacch%C4%81mi&f=false)", which seems to work like Latin *rogō.*

---

Going beyond your question about **īre**, there may be better ways to word a Latin translation of "Buddhaṃ śaraṇaṃ gacchāmi": different word choices that might echo the Latin tradition more poetically or more clearly. For example, *salūs* might be perfect, due to its use in Christianity for "salvation", but a more literal translation of [śaraṇaṃ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A3#Noun_4), like [perfugium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=perfugium), might convey the meaning better. In particular, there may be a better-fitting verb, maybe something like **dēcurrō**. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%9A%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9B%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF#Sanskrit) reports that *gacchāmi* is cognate with Latin **veniō**, which might offer some possibilities for a translation that retains the terseness and character of the original.

Comment: Do you know of any examples where *ire* is used transitively like that? I don't recall ever seeing it used with a pure accusative of a person. (Also: *salus* is a state, *perfugium* is a place. Especially if it's something spiritual, I would vote for *salus*.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Indeed _ire_ is a choice I'm doubtful about, both because it usually takes a preposition and because I'm not sure how well it agrees with the notion of seeking aid. I'd suggest _petere,_ but that verb definitely wants a preposition. I'm checking further into this right now.

Comment: @BenKovitz *Petere* also changes the meaning quite a bit. It's a different thing to go to someone for something than to ask someone for something. As always, the best choice of words depends on context and precise meaning, more than can be conveyed with a simple English translation "I go to him for shelter".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=eo1) mention some examples where _ire_ is used transitively, like _i domum_ (repeatedly in [this scene](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0031:act=5:scene=2&highlight=i+domum%2C)), and mention that in poetry it occurs "with the acc. of the terminus".

Comment: @BenKovitz I'm still in doubt about using it with people. Indeed *ire domum/Romam/viam* is fine. That use in Plautus sounds weird to me. I wonder if there are any examples in prose or classical Latin.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure this isn't a well-formed construction: the dative of purpose is almost always in the context of a double dative and usually is with a form of *esse*. Furthermore, the "purpose" in such a sentence would be what a thing is for, not what my intention is. It would have to be: "Sit mihi saluti Iosaphatus"

Comment: @brianpck JoonasIlmavirta Thanks for the better-informed confirmation of my doubts. I deleted the attempt to use the dative.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use a single plain accusative with *ire* in cases like this.
As per Ben Kovitz's comment, I will refer to the person as Jehosaphat in English.

The verb *ire* is mostly used intransitively.
As in English, a preposition is needed: *ad Iosaphatum ire* is "to go to Jehosaphat".
Alterinatively, the compound verb *adire* can be used transitively, so *Iosaphatum adire* means (almost) the same thing.
The simplest way to say "I go to Jehosaphat" is *ad Iosaphatum eo*.

I would translate "for shelter" as *salutis causa* (genitive and ablative, "for the reason of safety") if you want to use *salus*.
*Salus* refers to the state of safety, not to a place.
If you want "shelter" to be a physical safe place, then I would use something like *confugium*, *tectum*, or *tutum*.
For a religious tone, also *ara* is also possible.
Any of these words needs to be in genitive: *congugii, tecti, tuti*.

Thus, I would translate you phrase as *ad Iosaphatum salutis causa eo*.

You could also do other things for a different tone.
For example, *ad Iosaphatum fuga eo*, "I go to Jehosaphat as a refugee".

Comment: "Refuge/safety" is the Sanskrit original that I was trying to replace with "salutem", is this incorrect?

Comment: @Caoimhghin For that purpose [*salus*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2052513) is indeed a good word. I would just use it in genitive (*salutis*) to go with the ablative *causa*.

Comment: Prompted by C.M. Weimer, I just learned that what I also misread as _Iosephatum_ is actually the accusative of _Iosaphatus_, commonly called in English "[Jehosaphat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehoshaphat)", an oft-referenced Biblical king of Judah.

Comment: It is also a name for the Buddha in Latin! History is a strange thing.

Comment: Is Latin able to form grammatically sound sentences using two accusatives and a verb at all then? Or is this a particular feature of Sanskrit?

Comment: @Caoimhghin What?? I had no idea. _Salus_ might be a better word choice than I thought, then—_if,_ that is, you want to echo the Christian notion of salvation. If not, then another synonym is probably better.

Comment: @Caoimhghin It is possible, but relatively few verbs allow it. For example: *Te rem doceo*, "I teach you the thing". Often at least one of the two accusatives in another language have to be replaced by a preposition (with suitable case) or a dative. And sometimes it's more natural to use a verb instead.

Comment: @BenKovitz I would not automatically connect *salus* with the Christian notion of salvation. Nothing keeps us (at least nothing keeps me) from using the word in its classical meaning.

Comment: @Caoimhghin Yes: "[Two Accusatives](https://books.google.com/books?id=CBsXAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22dative%20of%20the%20purpose%20or%20end%22&pg=PA244#v=onepage&q=%22two%20accusatives%22&f=false)". Hopefully there's a nice way to render this in three Latin words, nicely corresponding to the Sanskrit; it might work best with a verb other than _ire._

Comment: Can vādō be used in a double-accusative construction instead of ire?

Comment: @BenKovitz There are ways like *salvandus Iosaphatum adeo* in three words, but the tone is easily distorted.

Comment: @Caoimhghin No verb of motion can use a double accusative to my knowledge. But you might want to ask a separate question about this point if you want to be sure.